# SQL query for raster point samping within postgis

Tags: postgis

I am trying to update my table with the values from a raster stored within the database.

**Edit**:
I've posted the answer bellow: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/63655/6711

The query I'm trying to use is Q

```
update data.points_test_10000 
    set sdi_index = (
            select 
                st_value(rast,geom)  from 
                    rasters.sdi_4326 a,    
                    data.points_test_10000 b 
                where 
                    a.rast && b.geom
                    ) ;
```

but I'm getting the error:

`more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`

without the set statments the query works as it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ST_Intersects](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Intersects.html) to limit per entry

```sql
UPDATE data.points_test_10000 p SET sdi_index = 
    ST_value(r.rast,p.geom) 
        from 
            rasters.sdi_4326 r 
        where 
            ST_Intersects(p.geom,r.rast)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like this:

```
UPDATE data.points_test_10000 
    SET sdi_index = (
            SELECT 
                st_value(a,b.geom)  from 
                    rasters.sdi_4326 a,    
                    data.points_test_10000 b 
                WHERE 
                    (a.rast && b.geom) 
                    AND (b.id = data.points_test_10000.id) 
                    ) ;
```

Comment: no, unfortunately it gives the same error